# Chapter breaks in Word

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I want a clean "chapter break" between each chapter in my document. This would consist of simply a blank page with the title in the center and a clean design: something like one of word's default "Cover pages". Is there any theme or anything similar that allows this?

Note; you cannot add a cover sheet in the center of a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Section Break](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-section-break-HA010031073.aspx). It will not allow you to insert some design or theme. For that i would write a little VB Macro to take care of this - see description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff940072.aspx). The example given could be applied to every section break in a document.